# How to create ASP.NET page to act as a "proxy" for Silverlight WebClient?

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, webclient, feed

I need to create an ASP.NET application to access a URL, when this application is live it is able to access the feed URL correctly as the clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml are on the server but only allow non-localhost connections so the debug version won't connect.
How do I create a file, so this kind of link:

```
http://localhost/feed.aspx?item=ItemName
```

Can be used to pass-through to the RSS feed service live URL like:

```
http://www.example.com/feed.aspx?item=ItemName
```

So that I can develop my application via localhost as I can add a clientaccesspolicy and crossdomain file to this application so my Silverlight Application can access the live RSS service, while being developed without having to deploy it online every time I need to see what the application will look like.
A dummy RSS file is not suitable as I need to see various "Items" from the Feed.

Comment: I have searched online, including here and many answers are to create a proxy for the URL - just not how, I'm guessing you read in the URL information possibly with a WebClient in the ASP.NET page, then do what with the output is the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page, feed.aspx, must read the RSS feed you want Silverlight to display and display it.

- Use an HttpWebRequest in your .aspx page codebehind to get the RSS feed data
- Post the feed data out to the outgoing stream via Response.Write

Thus the page acts as a proxy.  Your Silverlight app will read the data from your local page as if it was a regular RSS feed.

Comment: That sounds like what I need - I was thinking about something like this, just needed to know if this was the right way to go.